# RegExp for 0:59 to 99:59 or 0 to 99

Tags: javascript, regex

I want the strict regular expression for `0:59` to `99:59` Hours. It should allow `0` to `99` Hours.
How could it be done.

---

```
/^([0-9]{1,2}(\:[0-5][0-9])?)$/
```

is working properly

Comment: 0:59, 1:00, 1:01, ... 99:00, ..., 99:59? Is 0:1 allowed?

Comment: i tried  /^\d{1,2}(\:(\[0-5][0-9]))?$/

Comment: @MayP: Try it this way `/\d{1,2}(:[0-5]\d)?/`

Comment: @niksvp: please post ur answer,this will be accepted answer

Comment: @MayP - Thanks, I posted it.. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Even something as simple as `\d{1,2}(:[0-5]\d)?` should suffice.

```
\d                 A digit
\d{1,2}            One or two digits
\d{1,2}:           One or two digits followed by :
\d{1,2}:[0-5]      One or two digits followed by : followed by a digit 0 to 5
\d{1,2}:[0-5]\d    ...followed by a digit (0 to 5) and another digit
\d{1,2}(:[0-5]\d)? ...making the :XX part optional due to the ?
```

**Second update:** Fixed to account for the optional :XX part.

Comment: @Jon: You need to change `\d{2}` to `\d{1,2}` in order to match something like `0:59`

Comment: @Jon: +1, but it seems digits through : `:59` are required optional from the title. ;)

Comment: @niksvp: Can you explain that a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way 
`/\d{1,2}(:[0-5]\d)?/`

This regex will also validate numbers from 0 to 99 with or without `:` and post data. :)

**UPDATE**

javascript code for the same would be like

```
var field1 = "0:00"
var regTime = /\d{1,2}(:[0-5]\d)?/ ;
if(field1 == field1.match(regTime)[0]){ alert('matches') }
```

Comment: @MayP - can you show your code, how are you using in `javscript`? Looking to it I can help you.

Comment: @niksvp : /\b\d{1,2}\b(.\d{1,2})?/

Comment: both side digits should not exceed two.it should allow single digit too

Comment: @MayP - this is `regex`, I am asking about your `javascript` function , how are you implementing it

Comment: var regTime=/\b\d{1,2}\b(.\d{1,2})?/ ; if(field1.match()==null){}

Comment: @MayP - your questions says you want `:` and now you say it is not working for decimal places. If you want it to work for decimal places then replace `:` by `.` Simple.. isn't it???